# Tooltip how to rename more than one equation

Tags: tooltip

Manual shows renaming of one equation in Tooltip.  If you have multiple equations in a single plot, how can I rename each equation??  Having Tooltip display lengthy equations if of little value, therefore a better nomenclature is needed, but it appears Mathematica will only allow one renaming???

[image: equation only]

[image: renaming applies same nomenclature to all lines]

Comment: This question is a bit too general and I have to admit that I do not understant the issue at all. Usually, it is helpful to give a short minimal example that highlights your problem.

Comment: Post Mathematica code rather than pictures of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
funcs = Hypergeometric2F1[2., 3., 4., #] & /@
   {x, x^2, Sin[x], Cos[x]};

Plot[
 Evaluate[Tooltip[#, #[[-1]]] & /@ funcs],
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[(Last /@ funcs), {.85, .35}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 20},
 PlotLabel -> Hypergeometric2F1[2., 3., 4., f[x]]]
```

[image]

Or

```
labels = {x, x^2, Sin[x], Cos[x]};

Plot[Evaluate[(Tooltip @@ #) & /@ Transpose[{funcs, labels}]],
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[labels, {.85, .35}],
 PlotRange -> {0, 20},
 PlotLabel -> Hypergeometric2F1[2., 3., 4., f[x]]]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, Bob, I was hoping for something simpler. When I see @, @@, /@, &/@ my eyes kind of glass over. I knew once, but lack of use I have forgotten again --  any good resources to explain what these symbols mean???

Comment: @ray - Highlight the symbol of interest and press `F1` on your keyboard for help. See also [`What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/9362)